# EFFICIENT sorting through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this has been my attempt so far; I used a previous answer with lambda which had a problem and then tried something else. My second method works but I'd like to know (if and) why it is inefficient. Also a fix would be nice.

```
people = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10},
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7}
]

# This did not work; I got '<filter object at 0x1020b7f28>' back, which I believe is the memory location itself.
result = filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Pam', people)
print(result)

# This is the attempt that works but looks very ugly.
def search(name):
    counter = 0
    for student in people:
        if student['name'] == name:
            print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(student['name'], student['age']))
            break
        else:
            counter += 1
    if counter == len(people):
        print("There are no students with that name.")
```

Comment: `filter` is lazy, call `tuple(...)` on it to realize it's result.

Comment: Do you mean "sorting of" or "search through"?

Comment: You do not need to keep a counter of the number of people. If you have cycled through all elements in the list and not found the name then you can assume the name is not in the list. Therefore keeping a counter and checking if it equals the length of the people is redundant, there are a few different ways you can go about this but instead of using "break" you can return from inside the if statement and keep the print statment outside of the for loop raw.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit counter variable. You know that if you reach the end of you didn't find a matching name, so just `print()` there:

```
def search(name):
    for student in people:
        if student['name'] == name:
            print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(student['name'], student['age']))
            return
    print("There are no students with that name.")
```

Note that this solution will still be ***O(n)*** - the same as your original. As @Erich mentioned, if you want a solution that will be ***O(1)***, use a dictionary to map each persons name to their specific attributes:

```
>>> people = {
'Tom': {'age': 10},
'Mark': {'age': 5},
'Pam': {'age': 7}
}
>>> def search(name):
    person = people.get(name, None)
    if person is not None:
        print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(name, person['age']))
    else:
        print("There are no students with that name.")


>>> search('Bobby')
There are no students with that name.
>>> search('Mark')
Mark is 5 years old.
>>> search('Timmy')
There are no students with that name.
>>>
```

Comment: We cannot assume name to be unique always, but still this solution makes search O(1).

Comment: @Afaq True. that is a valid point. If the user has duplicate names then this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The entire method can be summed up as:

```
def search(name):
    try:
        student = next(i for i in people if i['name'] == name)
        print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(student['name'], student['age']))
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        return False
```

Comment: This is the best answer for speedup. I would add an addendum: if you expect multiple entries to share a "name" attribute you may want to do a list comprehension rather than just keep the first element.

Answer (score 1):

First, your original attempt actually does work, it just is returning a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of a list. The reason it does this is so that filter can be lazily evaluated (i.e. no work done until you try to iterate over it). The following will work as you probably intended.

```
result = list(filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Pam', people))
```

However, I think it can be improved a bit by using a list comprehension instead of filter since you seem to want it evaluated.

```
result = [person for person in people if person.name == 'Pam']
```

Answer (score 0):

return True when you find else return False or you can return name or none

```
def search(name):
    counter = 0
    for student in people:
        if student['name'] == name:
            print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(student['name'], student['age']))
            return True

    return False
```

In Case of duplicate name return list or tuple

```
def search(name):
    name_list=[]
    for student in people:
        if student['name'] == name:
            print("{0} is {1} years old.".format(student['name'], student['age']))
            name_list.append((student['name'])

    return name_list
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that each entry is it's own object in that the list only stores  a pointer to the dictionary. Because of this you can't really know if the list contains a name in O(1) time, you need at least O(n).

If you want to use more memory you can store a set of the names but that is only a fast contains, not a fast access. The use case for this would be many queries that are not present happening.

If you are able to modify the data type I would recommend using a dictionary of dictionaries, where the key is each person's name. This allows you to access the intended person's information in O(1) time.

e.g.

```
my_dict = {
"Edward":{"age":10}
"Gerald":{"age":54}
"Rashim":{"age":23}
}
```

Which then allows you to do things like:

```
my_dict["Rashim"]["age"]
>23
```

Otherwise I think your solution is okay O(n) time.

Comment: This assumes no duplicate names, and modifies the original input.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that.